# Connecting windows 10pc to Ubuntu 14.04.04 Samba Server

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing

I am running a linux ubuntu 14.04.04 sambda server. I have created vpn through openvpn and my next step is to configure a file sharing service. To do this I have set-up a Samba server by following this website- https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/how-to-install-samba-server-on-ubuntu-12-04/
(I am aware that the directions are for an ubuntu 12.04 server.)
The problem I am running into is connecting my windows 10 PC to the samba server. These are the settings I have in my smbd.conf file:

```
#======================= Global Settings ===================================== 
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = ubuntu
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
#============================ Share Definitions ============================== 
[MyShare]
path = /samba/share 
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
[test]
path = /home/michael/test
valid users = michael
read only = no
```

When I try mapping my network drive to the samba server. Windows cannot find it. How do I find my server and establish the connection? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can contact the server VIA the VPN?

Have you tried pinging it by IP address and by hostname? (To get the Internal IP address of your server go to your command line and type ipconfig)

if you can ping via IP address and not by hostname you will need to map the drive as such \XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\Sharename (Replacing the X's with your internal IP address)

If you dont wish to map by IP address every time you will need to edit your windows 10 [Host File](https://www.petri.com/easily-edit-hosts-file-windows-10) to include the name of your server, confirm this has worked correctly by pinging the hostname in CMD.

Comment: I can can communicate with my server through vpn and I am able to successfully ping my server. I realize a potential problem is that is my server is being hosted on digitalcloud. To connect to my server via vpn I am using OpenVPN. My computer is which is connected to a domain name has its own IP which is served by the DHCP, then I have a public IP address. Instead of using my local IP address in the Samba.config files, should I be using my public IP address?